# How would I update a variable everytime a window is resized using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How would I update a variable in another function every time a window is resized?

The code is as follows:

```
$(window).resize(function() {                
    Here is the NewVarialble;
});


(function (a) {
    OldVariable;
    Want to update the OldVarible with NewVariable;
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var resizeMe = function (newVar) {
    var oldVar = newVar;
}

$(window).resize(function (r) {  
    console.log(r);
    var newV = r;           
    resizeMe(newV);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what problem you are having but it seems to be simply regarding scope.

This might be useful reading for scope etc
http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

here is a working version - on js fiddle with the code pasted below, I'm not recommending using a variable on the window object, its simply for demonstration

http://jsfiddle.net/6B93N/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){// wrapper function / scope change as appropriate

        window.OldVariable =  -1; // placed globally but change as appropriate

        $(window).resize(function() {
            var NewVariable; // null initially

            NewVariable = Math.random();// assign a random number
            updateOldVar(NewVariable);
        });


        function updateOldVar(a) {
            window.OldVariable = a;
            //console.log(window.OldVariable);
        }


        $('.testbtn').on('click', function() {
           console.log(window.OldVariable);
        });



    });
```

Further to the comment below 
**EDIT:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {// wrapper function / scope change as appropriate

        var d = {
          divalayerWidth: 0,
          divalayerHeight: 0
        };

        $(window).resize(onWindowResize);

        function onWindowResize(e){
            updateD(d, e.target.outerWidth, e.target.outerHeight);
        }

        function updateD(d, w, h){

            d.divalayerWidth = w;
            d.divalayerHeight = h;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Hi Lewis,

Actually I want to update d.divlayerWidth and d.divlayerHeight value with new windowWidth and new windowHeight everytime I resize the window. The current script is like bellow:

    (function (a) {

        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();

        a.divlayer = function (b, c) {
            var d = this;
            d.init = function () {
                d.divlayerWidth = windowWidth;
                d.divlayerHeight = windowHeight;
            }
        }

})(jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

Either make the variable a global variable (bad idea) or move the resize block into the self executing anonymous function like so:

```
(function (a) {
    OldVariable;
    $(window).resize(function() {                
        this now has access to oldvariable
    });    
})(jQuery);
```